# Is there a simplified way of checking if the data renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, operators

When fetching data that is undefined on the first render we use the short-circuit `&&` operator e.g `data && data.doSomething` to check if it has already rendered inorder to execute something else we get an error.

So if you have n different loops that is depending on that data, that means you have to check it n times before you loop it 
 Example: you are in a case to loop that data 3 times so you need to check it 3 times.
`data && data.map` `data && data.reduce` `data && data.filter` which is kinda repetitious specially if you also have components that is depending on that data `data && <Component />`

I tried putting the data on the useEffect(setData) and get the data from state still you need to do check it.

fetching state 
`data = useSelector(state => state.data)` 
 
1st loop getting all user 
`const allUser = data && data.map.(data => data.user)` 
2nd loop filtering user 
`const allAge = allUser && allUser.filter(user => user.age > 18)`
and so on.

As you can see, 1st loop is depending on the fetch data(data), and the second loop is depending on the 2nd loop(allUser). So you have to chain-checking it.I know you can get that in a combined map and filter, but supposed you need to that.

Comment: Please show a concrete example, also it is very weird that this question gets insta-upvoted.

Comment: My answer stands, you don't have to use `&&` operator here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) which supported out of the box in major React starters (CRA, Gatsby, Next.js).

```
const App = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {data?.map()}
      {data?.reduce()}
      {data?.filter()}
      {!data && <LoadingComponent />}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: worked, but you still need to assign the return value to a variable ex const newData = data?.map

Comment: You can do whatever you like with the returned value